# Create a requirements.txt file to get the MyBinder link to share with Github

Tags: anaconda, requirements.txt, virtual-environment

I created an environment with anaconda, I created a folder in which I put all the notebooks that I wanted to share. I created the requirements.txt file using pip freeze and copied all the packages showed. I have initialized a github repository and added the link in MyBinder.org, I launched the page but it says that it failed to compile. I suppose the requirements.txt is not valid.

How can I create a proper requirements.txt file?

Comment: What is the link to your repository?

Comment: https://github.com/Torraf-MI/Trading-Strategies-with-Python#trading-strategies-with-python

Comment: Can you explain me how to properly do the requirements.txt file?

Comment: Looks like you swtiched to using conda via an `environment.yml` configuration file from using just `pip` via `requirements.txt`? Currently it won't build because you should remove `nbclassic` from your list as it is incompatible. (Both classic and JupyterLab get installed by default if you allow defaults.) You can put a special `environment.yml` that Binder will specifically use by placing it in a sub-directory called `binder`, see [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/about.html?highlight=root#can-i-put-my-configuration-files-outside-the-root-of-my-repository).